# Calculate total votes using data from files

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am a beginner coder and don't have much experience in java. I am confused about a program that I have to code using arrays, if-else statements, and loops.

The assignment is:

> Write a program that uses the file ElectionVotes.txt, which contains state names and electoral votes, and the file ElectionData.txt, which contains state names and total votes for each candidate,  to calculate the number of electoral votes earned by Obama and Romney in the 2012 election. Your program should build a lookup table with the state names, another table with the associated electoral votes for that state. The output should show two numbers - the total electoral votes for each candidate.

I have tried to do it, but I don't know if this will work.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Electoral_Votes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str, filename, filename2;
        double[] States = new double[51];
        int[] ObamaVote = new int[51];
        int[] RomneyVote = new int[51];
        int high, low, high2, low2, EV;
        double Total, sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("ElectionVotes.txt"));
            str = inputFile.nextLine();

            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                str = inputFile.next();
                States[i] = inputFile.nextDouble();
                EV = inputFile.nextInt();

                for (i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {
                    RomneyVote = getRomneyV();
                    ObamaVote = getObamaV();
                    if (RomneyVote > ObamaVote) {
                        RomneyVote[i] += EV;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }

    public static double[] getElectionData() {
        double[] States = new double[51];
        int[] ObamaVote = new int[51];
        int[] RomneyVote = new int[51];
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("ElectionData.txt"));
            String str = inputFile.nextLine();

            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                str = inputFile.next();
                States[i] = inputFile.nextDouble();
                ObamaVote[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
                RomneyVote[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        return States;
    }

    public static int[] getRomneyV() {
        double[] States = new double[51];
        int[] ObamaVote = new int[51];
        int[] RomneyVote = new int[51];
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("ElectionData.txt"));
            String str = inputFile.nextLine();

            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                str = inputFile.next();
                States[i] = inputFile.nextDouble();
                ObamaVote[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
                RomneyVote[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        return RomneyVote;
    }

    public static int[] getObamaV() {
        double[] States = new double[51];
        int[] ObamaVote = new int[51];
        int[] RomneyVote = new int[51];
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("ElectionData.txt"));
            String str = inputFile.nextLine();

            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                str = inputFile.next();
                States[i] = inputFile.nextDouble();
                ObamaVote[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
                RomneyVote[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        return ObamaVote;
    }
}
```

Comment: What issues are you having? What does your current code output?

Comment: The current issue is that the file is not reading, and I can't figure out how to store data once I read it from a file.

Comment: Are you getting an exception. If so, put that in your question.

Comment: are you sure your file is in the correct directory? what do you mean your file "is not reading" your txt file is not suppose to read anything.

Comment: I meant that the file is not being read/found by netbeans. The files are in the src folder.